# Undefined window.innerWidth in Safari 10.1.1

Tags: javascript, css, browser, safari, cross-browser

I have a script, which adjusts font-size based on viewport size.

Looks like it works everywhere but in Safari (I checked only 10.1.1 version).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have selected "All" in the top part of your developer tools. Otherwise it will only show you errors and therefore you will only see `undefined`.

Answer (score -2):

Use `screen.width` instead of `window.innerWidth`

Caution: in desktop this serves the purpose only if the browser window is always kept maximized

Hope it helps

Comment: The device's width is completely irrelevant. Not every user browses with the window maximized.

Comment: @twistedpixel kindy mind to read the caution

Comment: I did read the caution. Your solution is an edge-case solution and does not work most of the time.